# How to load Grapes JS inline without canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, grapesjs

I am trying to use grapes Js to edit the HTML (i.e font size, color, etc). I am loading the HTML and CSS dynamically into the grapes Js.

But I want to know is there a way to have the functionality to edit the font size directly in that HTML without grapes js canvas?.

please find the below code that I am using to load the html and css of the HTML into grapes JS

```
const createGrapesJSTemplate = (body) => {
    const str = `<div>
                    <div class="panel__top">
            <div class="panel__basic-actions"></div>
            <div class="panel__switcher"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="editor-row">
            <div class="editor-canvas">
              <div id="gjs">
                ${body}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel__right" id="panel__right">
              <div class="layers-container"></div>
              <div class="styles-container"></div>
              <div class="add-class" id="add-class">
                <label htmlFor="class">Class Name</label>
                <input
                  style="margin-top: 2%; color:black"
                  type="text"
                  id="add-class-input"
                />
                <button style="background-color:red; color:white" onclick="addClass()">
                  Add
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="doneChanges" class="doneChanges" style="margin-top:5%; display:flex; justify-content: flex-start">
                <button onclick="onClickingDone()" style="background-color:red; color:white">
                  Done
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                </div>`

    let html

    if (false) {
    } else {
        var dom = document.createElement('div')
        dom.innerHTML = str;
        html = dom;
    }

    $("body").html(html)
}

const appendGrapesJSScript = (style) => {

    const grapesJSScript = document.createElement("script")
    grapesJSScript.innerHTML = `editor = grapesjs.init({
      // Indicate where to init the editor. You can also pass an HTMLElement
      container: "#gjs",
      // Get the content for the canvas directly from the element
      // As an alternative we could use: "components: '<h1>Hello World Component!</h1>'",
      fromElement: true,
      // Size of the editor

      // Disable the storage manager for the moment
      storageManager: false,
      // Avoid any default panel
      layerManager: {
        appendTo: ".layers-container",
      },
      //we define the panel right as layout manager
      panels: {
        defaults: [
          {
            id: "layers",
            el: ".panel__right",
            // Make the panel resizable
            draggable: true
          },

          // code for layers and style manager
          {
            id: "panel-switcher",
            el: ".panel__switcher",
            buttons: [
              {
                id: "show-layers",
                active: true,
                label: "Layers",
                command: "show-layers",
                // Once activated disable the possibility to turn it off
                togglable: true,
              },
              {
                id: "show-style",
                active: true,
                label: "Styles",
                command: "show-styles",
                togglable: true,
              },
              {
                id: "add-class",
                active: true,
                label: "CLS",
                togglable: true,
                command: "add-classes",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      // The Selector Manager allows to assign classes and
      // different states (eg. :hover) on components.
      // Generally, it's used in conjunction with Style Manager
      // but it's not mandatory
      // selectorManager: {
      //   appendTo: ".styles-container",
      // },
      styleManager: {
        appendTo: ".styles-container",
        sectors: [
          {
            name: "Dimension",
            open: false,
            // Use built-in properties
            buildProps: ["background-size", "margin", "padding", "width", "height", "font-size", "border-radius"],
            // Use "properties" to define/override single property
            properties: [
              {
                // Type of the input,
                // options: integer | radio | select | color | slider | file | composite | stack
                type: "integer",
                name: "The width", // Label for the property
                property: "width", // CSS property (if buildProps contains it will be extended)
                units: ["px", "%"], // Units, available only for 'integer' types
                defaults: "auto", // Default value
                min: 0, // Min value, available only for 'integer' types
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Extra",
            open: false,
            buildProps: [
              "background-color",
              "box-shadow",
              "custom-prop",
              "font-size",
            ],
            properties: [
              {
                id: "custom-prop",
                name: "Font Size",
                property: "font-size",
                type: "integer",
                defaults: "32px",
                units: ["px", "%"],
                min: 0,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },

      blockManager: {},
    });

    editor.Panels.addPanel({
      id: "panel-top",
      el: ".panel__top",
    });
    editor.Panels.addPanel({
      id: "basic-actions",
      el: ".panel__basic-actions",
      buttons: [
        {
          id: "export",
          className: "btn-open-export",
          label: "Exp",
          command: "export-template",
          context: "export-template", // For grouping context of buttons from the same panel
        },
      ],
    });

    // Define commands
    editor.Commands.add("show-layers", {
      getRowEl(editor) {
        return editor.getContainer().closest(".editor-row");
      },
      getLayersEl(row) {
        return row.querySelector(".layers-container");
      },

      run(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "230px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "none";
        const lmEl = this.getLayersEl(this.getRowEl(editor));
        lmEl.style.display = "";
      },
      stop(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "none";
        const lmEl = this.getLayersEl(this.getRowEl(editor));
        lmEl.style.display = "none";
      },
    });
    editor.Commands.add("show-styles", {
      getRowEl(editor) {
        return editor.getContainer().closest(".editor-row");
      },
      getStyleEl(row) {
        return row.querySelector(".styles-container");
      },

      run(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "230px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "flex";
        const smEl = this.getStyleEl(this.getRowEl(editor));
        smEl.style.display = "";
      },
      stop(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "none";
        const smEl = this.getStyleEl(this.getRowEl(editor));
        smEl.style.display = "none";
      },
    });

    editor.Commands.add("add-classes", {
      run(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "230px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("add-class").style.display = "flex";
      },
      stop(editor, sender) {
        document.getElementById("panel__right").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("doneChanges").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("add-class").style.display = "none";
      },
    });

    editor.setStyle(${JSON.stringify(style)})
    window.editor = editor    
    `

    document.body.appendChild(grapesJSScript)
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out to load the grapesjS text editor directly inside the webpage without grapes JS Canvas?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.